# Message Evaluation

Tags: elixir

When my GenServer is receiving messages from outside queue/topic it always ends up n handle_info [being called from outside].So, just wanted to know,

1. Is is good to have all messages received this way as i have to call function by evaluating the messages all the time, or is there any other way as well. 
   For example, User sharing his details, sending message to other users etc.

   I created one GenServer and started the process and now clients can send messages to some queue to register their details[name, phone no etc].
2. Now, when new message received from client i can not get any PID from handle_info. 
   So, how can i make process specific to that user.

```rb
    def handle_info({_, data}, state) do
      {:noreply, state}
    end
```

Comment: You can send `self` in the message to the GenServer...

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by your question, but yeah you can call self anywhere and get the Pid of the process that you are at the moment of execution. The GenServer is just a generic behaviour on top of your normal process. Here you can find good information about GenServers: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/clients-and-servers

Comment: The best way to call a GenServer is using `GenServer.call/2`. As Uri Agassi pointed out, if you need the caller in there, you can just pass it explicitly with `self()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `GenServer` (or erlangs gen_server) you should not send messeages to process explicitly (with `!`) but rather use interface functions like [call](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/GenServer.html#call/3) (if you expect some value returned from server) and [cast](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/GenServer.html#cast/2) (if you just want to send some date, and don't need to wait for response.

Second thing is you should also not expose your module clients to `GenServer` interface.  Rather than making them call `GenServer:call` you should wrap it in some funtion in your module.  If you implementing some king you counter you could write something like this

```
def increase(counter) do 
   GenServer.cast(conter, {:increase})
done

def get_count(counter) do 
   GenServer.call(counter, {get_coung})
done
```

and handle both of them in respective `handle...` functions.